# In Regex, Using a named capture group, how do I designate to capture the user_agent field in an access_combined log?

Tags: regex, logging, proxy

I'm working on bringing in some bluecoat proxy logs. I'm using named capture groups in regex to parse the fields that may or may not be present in the logs. The majority of the fields are space delimited. The user_agent field, which is not always present in the entries is within quotation marks (see bolded text within sample below). I've included a portion of my regex, so you can see the pattern I have been following. Any suggestions on how to capture all of the data within the quotation marks as one group using a named capture group?
TIA,
Sharon

> 2014-03-27 12:39:40 76 10.3.63.13 200 TCP_NC_MISS 455 1236 GET http
>   www.google-analytics.com 80 /collect
>   ?v=1&_v=j17&a=1102608266&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.about.com%2Fod%2Fpersonalizegoogle%2Fss%2FcreateAlertSBS.htm&dr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D8%26cad%3Drja%26uact%3D8%26sqi%3D2%26ved%3D0CFMQFjAH%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fgoogle.about.com%252Fod%252Fpersonalizegoogle%252Fss%252FcreateAlertSBS.htm%26ei%3DBxw0U6rAAq3JsQTenoG4Ag%26usg%3DAFQjCNHx6zp6l6jvorcEaz3tC7dS_yH_0g%26sig2%3DKSZV_0g8bK1ayjB8jVqscA%26bvm%3Dbv.63738703%2Cd.cWc&ul=en-us&de=windows-1252&dt=How%20to%20Create%20a%20Google%20Alert&sd=24-bit&sr=1600x900&vp=1583x809&je=1&fl=12.0%20r0&_u=eCC~&cid=434094455.1394395551&tid=UA-44417706-1&cg1=Articles&cd1=google&cd2=compute&cd3=20906&cd4=29&cd5=aj-about-premium&cd6=primedia_google%20tt29%20primedia_site_targeting%20test0&cd7=8&cd8=1&cd9=0&cd10=personalizegoogle%2F&cd15=&cm1=522&z=435946251
>   - - - www.google-analytics.com image/gif http://google.about.com/od/personalizegoogle/ss/createAlertSBS.htm
>   **"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"** OBSERVED "Web Ads/Analytics" - 163.252.254.201
>   74.125.228.197 52349

portion of the regex i'm using to parse this into named capture groups:
`(?<cs_authgroup>[^\s]*)\s(?<s_hierarchy>[^\s]*)\s(?<s_supplier_name>[^\s]*)\s(?<rs_Content_Type>[^\s]*)\s(?<cs_referer>[^\s]*)\s`

**The next field in this group is for `<user_agent>`...any ideas on how to get the bolded sample in there, or move on to the next capture group if that field is null?**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to capture everything within quotes use this as a start `(?<user_agent>".*?")` http://rubular.com/r/CUQ5gFi8mM and http://rubular.com/r/vulCkheohN